# passing data using router

Tags: angular

I have a problem with passing data to other component. Here is the example.

```
 onEdit(data) {
    this.router.navigate(["/edit", { state: data }], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
    });
  }
```

And my router `ts` file:

```
{
    path: "edit",
    component: ServiceTimeGoalUpdateComponent,
    resolve: {
      serviceTimeGoal: ServiceTimeGoalResolve
    },
    data: {
      pageTitle: "ServiceTimeGoals",
      data: "data"
    }
  },
```

And above snippets gives me:
[image]

What i exactly want is when i click to edit button from the list it should be navigate to `edit` and with some data. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@batgerel, You has an error in your code. must be

```
this.router.navigate(['./edit'], 
   { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, state: { data } })
```

And, if your component it's not the main app, in ngOnInit

```
   this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
                take(1), //take(1) is for unsubscribe
                map(() => window.history.state)
            ).subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your routing to something like below,

you can use QueryParams for your scenario

```
 this.router.navigate(["/edit"], { 
      queryParams: { dataParam : value, dataPara2: value }
 });
```

get the value by subscribing to [**`ActivatedRoute`**](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in Component.

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params['dataParam '],params['dataPara2']);
});
```

you can also remove the `data` param in Routing initialization.

**Edit**

If you have already a common service use that otherwise create service class like below,

```
export class ServiceName {
    private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.data.asObservable();
    }

    setData(param: any): void {
        this.data.next(param);
    }
  }
```

then you can call the `data` methods in component before navigating the router, and get the data with `getData()` method.

```
  this.service.setData(data);
  this.router.navigate(["/edit", { state: data }], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
  });
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: my data is array.

Comment: Yes. It's getting datas from database. And need to update it with other component.

Comment: it's better to use a common service between them to transfer large data than router...

Comment: can you give me some clue ?

Comment: updated the answer, try to give some initial value and check more here https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services