# Angular: no way to pass an object through a router?

Tags: angular, router

I've been trying to find a simple solution.

I have a for loop displaying a list of items. clicking on one of the items routes you to the detailed component and I just want the selected item to be available in the detailed component. For some reason there is no simple solution (that I am aware of). I would expect there to be something like this:

``

``

that's what I want. but, of course it doesn't work.

so instead I am passing the item id as a queryParams element, and then doing a Service call on the detail component to retrieve the item. It works fine but seems like a lot of work to do something that should be so simple.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't want to pay an object through a router. Instead pass an id and then re-look up the item on the new page. That way if you refresh the new page, everything still works.

Answer (score 2):

> Objects passing by routing is limited options. Using a service is the
>   better option. If you provide a service instance by the parent
>   component, then the same instance gets injected in parent and child
>   and you have the shared data available immediately.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-communicating-between-components-1gunkw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that is talking about parent-child components of the same view, as opposed to a view component that routes to another completely different view.

Comment: Yes, You are right. angular route impact the URL when you pass as a parameter to route.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
        <a [routerLink]="['/product/',product.id]"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that doesn't work. and even if it did, it would simply pass the id. I am hoping to pass the entire object (product) in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

What i think about why there is no way to pass an object through a router is because if you pass the data and made it available on the `route2`,

the data is available on the `route2` just because it is passed from `route1`.

What happens if you refresh `route2`??

from where will you get the data for `route2`, your page would collapse.

Comment: I don't know. I am used to IOS objective C development and it's extremely simple passing any kind of data object from one VC to another. But maybe you are right. In IOS there is no such refresh concept.

Comment: and mobile app development is different from web app development. mobile app development will have a life cycle of its own, even if you minimize/terminate the app and open it again, it will open some specific screen. like `onResume` event or something.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 7.2 you can pass argument to router, see [this great link](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb)

In .html you must use [state], e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [routerLink]="['/item-details']" [state]=item>
```

Two get the state you has two options, from a component not main-app, see 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796745/passing-data-using-router/58797605#58797605), from the main-app you can subscribe to router.events

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
  map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
).subscribe((res:any)=>{
   console.log(res)
})
```

NOTE: if use this aproach, remember that if you access directly to your "item-details.component", you has any "item"