# send data to another component through route in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular7-router

I am working on an angular application and realized that in the latest versions of angular, data can be transferred one component to other through routes. I have gone through some blogs but I am not very clear of how to do that.

My code

component1.ts

```
sendMessageto2() {
    par = this.param
    this.router.navigate(['/vav'],{state : {data : {par}}})
    console.log(this.param)
  }
```

I want to pass a variable `this.param` to component2

component1.html

```
<area shape="rect" coords="818,232,917,262" (click)="sendMessageto2()">
```

component2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
    .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))  
  }
```

I am not sure how to get this data in the component2 .I get an error for `map`. Could not find map.Can some one help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Comment: I tried but I have an issue, edited the question

Comment: get the data in a component not in main.ts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796745/passing-data-using-router/58797605#58797605, get the data in main.component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886303/angular-no-way-to-pass-an-object-through-a-router/58891470#58891470.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing data you can do this

```
this.router.navigate(["/vav", { 'data': data }]);
```

For receiving on other page

```
constructor(public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute){}
route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let data = params['data']
    });
```

Comment: is it `route` or `router` ?

Comment: @cvg thanks for pointing out i forgot to add public route: ActivatedRoute.

Comment: also should I make some changes in the `app-routing.module.ts` ?

Comment: not required. it is used to fetch the param value.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the data you are trying to pass is a string. Define your route like this,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component : C1Component },
  { path:'vav', component : C2Component },
];
```

When routing, add the value in URL as `queryParams`,

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
        "data"   : encodeURIComponent('Your data'),
    }
};

this.router.navigate(["vav"], navigationExtras);
```

Fetch the `queryParams` in second component using `ActivateRoute`,

```
decodeURIComponent(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['data']);
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zw742

> If the data is an object, `JSON.stringify()` it before encoding and `JSON.parse()` it after decoding.

Comment: Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Comment: I get an error at `params`

Comment: I've made it simpler with `queryParams`. Check the updated answer and demo.

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass like this:

**routing.ts**

```
{path: 'component2', component: YourComponent2} // configure it in the routing file
```

**component1.ts**

```
private router: Router // import router
this.router.navigate(['/component2', {id: '1', name: 'surjeet'}]);
```

**component2.ts**

```
private route: ActivatedRoute // import ActivatedRoute
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

On component 2

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param') ; 
  }
```

'param' value is the value that has been added to the url from component 1 .